# requirements.txt requirement specifier, = "*"

Tags: python, pip

I'm seeing a requirements file with the `"*"` requirement specifier, is this supposed to work?

**requirements.txt**

```
jupyterlab = "*"
tensorflow-gpu = "*"
imageio = "*"
```

and the repository suggest me to install it as `pip install -r ./requirements.txt`. Any Ideas?

**Error:**

ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'jupyterlab = "*"' (from line 1 of ./requirements.txt)
Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?

Comment: Did that *not* work? `*` is a wildcard per e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers, but that looks like a snippet of pipfile not requirements.txt. Give a [mre], link to the package, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the question, that is a `requirements.txt` and I've pasted the error into the question.

Comment: Right, a valid `requirements.txt` has `name==version`. That looks more like e.g. https://github.com/pypa/pipfile. Have you reported this to whoever maintains the repo?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point. I'll inform the repo owner's, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` instead of `==`.
Also, `pip` does not like `*` as a version specifier, but it accepts `1.*` for instance.